# How do you properly use Azure DevOps functions in a variable template?

Tags: function, variables, azure-devops

How can I use the Azure DevOps `counter` function in a variable template?

Up until now, I have been using the `counter` function to set a variable in an pipeline and the value has been set as expected - it started at 1 and has incremented every time I run the pipeline.

Variable template - /Variables/variables--code--build-and-deploy-function-app.yml

```
variables:
- name: major
  value: '1'
- name: minor
  value: '0'
- name: patch
  value: $[counter(format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']), 1)]
- name: branch
  ${{ if eq( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master' ) }}: 
    value: ''
  ${{ if ne( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master' ) }}: 
    value: -${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
```

However, after moving the exact same variables in to a [variable template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse), the value of `counter` is the literal value specified in the template.

Digging further in to the documentation for templates, I found some words on [template expression functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#template-expressions), together with an example of how to use a functon -

> You can use [general functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions) in your templates. You can also use a few template expression functions.

Given that `counter` is listed on the page that the link above refers to, I assumed I would be able to use it. However, no matter what I've tried, I can't get it to work. Here are a few examples -

```
${{ counter('${{ format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) }}', 1) }}

${{ counter(format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']), 1) }}

$[counter('${{ format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) }}', 1)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

## Update

My variable template is as above, an here is how I use it in the pipeline -

```
pr: none
trigger: none
    
variables:
- template: ../Variables/variables--code--build-and-deploy-function-app.yml

name: ${{ variables.major }}.${{ variables.minor }}.${{ variables.patch }}${{ variables.branch }}
```

The expanded pipeline obtained from logs after a run is as follows -

```
pr:
  enabled: false
trigger:
  enabled: false
variables:
- name: major
  value: 1
- name: minor
  value: 0
- name: patch
  value: $[counter(format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']), 1)]
- name: branch
  value: -CS-805
name: 1.0.$[counter(format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']), 1)]-CS-805
```

As can be seen from the extended pipeline, the `patch` variable isn't being evaluated, resulting in the `name` containing the literal value -

[image]

Comment: Hi @David Gard. Test to use the same variables in template and it could work fine. You could refer to the answer and check if I miss some key steps. If it doesn't help, you may share Yaml sample about this issue.This helps me understand how you use variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted the same variables into the template and the `patch` variable works as expected. It seems that your counter is correct.

Here are my sample, you could refer to it:

Template Yaml: build.yml

```
variables:
- name: major
  value: '1'
- name: minor
  value: '0'
- name: patch
  value: $[counter(format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']), 1)]
```

Azure-Pipelines.yml

```
name: $(patch)

trigger:
- none

variables:
- template: build.yml  

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- script: echo $(patch)
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

In order to make the result more intuitive, I set `patch` variable to build name.

Here is the result:

[image]

**Update:**

Test with $(varname) and it could work as expected.

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- template: build.yml  


name: $(major).$(minor)-$(patch)$(branch)
```

Result:

[image]

The $(varname) means runtime before a task executes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that once I'd moved variables in to a template, I could no longer reference then using `$(varName)` and instead had to switch to `${{ variables.varName }}` - it's interesting that this appears to have worked for you. I have updated my question to include details of this, along with a snippet from my pipeline and the same snippet from the expanded template obtained from the logs.

Comment: Hi @DavidGard. Thanks for your information. Test with `${{ variables.varName }}`, I could reproduce this issue. But the $(Varname) could work fine. Please check my update.  When you use $(varname), what problem did you encounter.

Comment: I think I've found the issue - as well as the variable template, I have stages in templates. The name of some of jobs defined by one of those stages includes the value of a parameter passed in from the pipeline, the value of which is `$(functionAppSlot)`, which is set in the variable template. This results in a failure to even start the pipeline run. Error - Stage BVT_UK_South_Internal job Update_App_Settings_In_$(functionAppSlot) has an invalid name. So I've changed references to `$(functionAppSlot)` to `${{ functionAppSlot }}` instead, and now the pipeline is running and the name is correct.

Comment: So I think the issue with `${{ patch }}` is a red herring, caused by me thinking I'd have to change EVERY variable reference to `{{ variables.varName }}` do to the error in the previous comment. However, it doesn't really feel right that I should have to use different syntax to define one variable - it would be great to know why that is, and whether the issue will be addressed in the future.

Comment: Great! Glad to know that this issue has been resolved. Maybe you could refer to this doc to learn  variable syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax Different syntax means getting values at different times

Comment: OK, I get it. Because I use the value of `functionAppSlot` in a job name, that particular variable needs to be processed at compile time, otherwise the template is invalid at runtime because the job name contains the yet to be processed `$(functionAppSlot)`, which is only processed at runtime, before a task executes. Thanks for the help.